# Auto-repair for Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, editor

Lately I've been having problems with Android Studio, mostly what it seems with code synchronization. For example, I'll comment out a section which is causing the issue and sync the project before running it again, only to have the Android Monitor point out to the line in comments, as if it still interprets it as code. I'm curious what you would recommend? A full reinstall? Is there any feature that restores default settings and would alleviate this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try File/Invalidate caches and restrat, see [link](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/cleaning-system-cache.html)

Comment: Thanks, I reckon this might do the trick.